# Static type performance with and without static constructor

Tags: c#, .net

In his [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#performance) about singletons in paragraph "Performance vs Laziness", Jon Skeet writes the following lines:

> If your singleton instance is referenced within a relatively tight
>   loop, this can make a (relatively) significant performance difference.

As I understand he means the difference between two cases: with and without static constructor.

But the reason of this difference is stil vague for me despite these words:

> This can increase performance as it allows the JIT compiler to make a
>   single check (for instance at the start of a method) to ensure that
>   the type has been initialized, and then assume it from then on.

And if static constructor exists what does JIT-compiler do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer about performance through [CA1810 rule explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CA1810%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29&rd=true).

> When a type declares an explicit static constructor, the just-in-time
>   (JIT) compiler adds a check to each static method and instance
>   constructor of the type to make sure that the static constructor was
>   previously called. Static initialization is triggered when any static
>   member is accessed or when an instance of the type is created.
>   However, static initialization is not triggered if you declare a
>   variable of the type but do not use it, which can be important if the
>   initialization changes global state. When all static data is
>   initialized inline and an explicit static constructor is not declared,
>   Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) compilers add the
>   beforefieldinit flag and an implicit static constructor, which
>   initializes the static data, to the MSIL type definition. When the JIT
>   compiler encounters the beforefieldinit flag, most of the time the
>   static constructor checks are not added. Static initialization is
>   guaranteed to occur at some time before any static fields are accessed
>   but not before a static method or instance constructor is invoked.
>   Note that static initialization can occur at any time after a variable
>   of the type is declared.

Answer (score 1):

There is no much performance difference in the both approaches. Unless you are calling them in a tight loop.

The big difference between a singleton and a static class is that singletons can implement interfaces. And you can pass the singleton class as parameter.

***EDIT***

---

> Unless you are calling them in a tight loop

The singleton-instance variant is slower because you have to access two memory operations to get to the value.

1. Static storage
2. and normal memory storage

   But for a normal call it is negligible difference. When you are calling it inside a huge loop, that difference will be increase and Static class will perform better in that case.

Comment: "Unless you are calling them in a tight loop" - and what happens then?

Comment: Still not clear. Slower than what? Any of examples given in the article implies these two operations, doesn't it?

Comment: Slower than what?? we are talking about only two types right? what i told is singleton is slower than static

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet is actually referring to when you create the instance of your singleton object. If you create it in the static constructor then the framework ensures that it gets executed only once and no locks need to be taken out.

However if you use Lazy or use some custom code to generate the instance when it is first accessed then this can be slower.

He is saying that if you access the singleton instance in a loop then a static constructor will be quicker.

Comment: I'm not sure because in part "Fourth version - not quite as lazy, but thread-safe without using locks" he writes: "Also note that it affects performance, as discussed near the bottom of the page." But the example contains no locks or Lazy.